# Problem adding click event handler with JQuery Mobile in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile, android-browser

I am having a strange problem with the android browser.  Hopefully this is something I am doing fundamentally wrong and not a JQuery bug.  I have tried the following code in Firefox and Chrome which work fine.  However when I try it in the Android browser, clicking on the Get Tweets button does not work.  It seems to be an issue with JQuery Mobile because when I add the event to a normal non JQuery Mobile object it binds correctly and the console.log fires.  I have tried with both alpha and beta versions of JQuery Mobile with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
            .chkTag { color: black; }
            /*.chkFeed { color: black; }*/
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitter/style/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css"     />        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="twitter/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="twitter/js/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js">       
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $(".tweetjack").click(function() {
            console.log('test');
        });
        console.log('page loaded');
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .profile img { width: 48px; height: 48px; display: inline; float: left; padding-right: 10px; }
        /*.ui-collapsible-contain { max-height: 950px; min-height: 950px; }*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="d">
        <div id="header" data-role="header">
            <h1>Twitter App</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="1" class="tweetjack" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"><h3>Get Tweets</h3><p id="text1"></p><div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"><h3 date-theme="a">Filter</h3></div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
            <a class="tweetjack"><h2>BT</h2></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This script also fails in android browser only.

```
$('#page').live('pagecreate',function(event){
      console.log('page loaded');
      $(".tweetjack").click(function() {
            console.log('test');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try using the 'pagecreate' event rather than $(document).ready(): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: I replaced .ready() with this and again the same issue.  Click event handler works fine in all browsers except android mobile.

Comment: How are you viewing the console?

Comment: In firefox I use firebug, in Android I use Dalvik Debug monitor.  The 'page loaded' log is seen in ddms, but the click log is not.  Both are seen in firebug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems I was simply doing it the old fashioned JQuery way when there is actually a JQuery Mobile way of doing these things now.  Here is the correct code.

```
$('#page').live('pagecreate',function(event){
  console.log('page loaded');
  $(".tweetjack").live('tap',function(event) {
      console.log('test');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQM seems to intercept clicks, and set the href to '#', which can cause some havoc if you're trying to intercept them.  This worked for me, to process the link before JQM gets to it:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
   $("a").bind("click", function(e){  fix_mobile_links(this, e)  });
}
```